# What is the temperature inside a methane/oxygen rocket engine?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, fuel, engines, temperature

Assuming a simple rocket engine, with a combustion chamber and de laval nozzle, fueled by liquid methane and liquid oxygen, what temperature must the combustion chamber, choke and nozzle withstand?

From a [university article](http://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4824&context=ujmm), the adiabatic temperature of a perfect mix would be about 5000C:

[image: adiabatic temperature]

However, when combustion products expand they cool, so this question could be rephrased as what pressures exist in the three main parts of the engine.

Really I am asking "how tough does the inside of a rocket engine need to be"? What is the max temperature and pressure the materials must be able to withstand?

Comment: "It's hot. Damn hot! Real hot! Hottest things is my shorts. I could cook things in it. A little crotch pot cooking."   (Robin Williams, Good Morning Vietnam)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a paper by [4 authors](http://www.dlr.de/Portaldata/55/Resources/dokumente/sart/0095-0212prop.pdf) that compares Kerosene engines to Methane engines. It states the chamber temperature of a Methane rocket is 3533K, comparable to the RP-1 3676K chamber temperature. The optimal temperature in a vacuum is 3563K, compared to 3701K. So it seems the temperature constraints are very similar to RP-1 rockets. See the paper for other comparisons.

This isn't the highest temperature, but results in the highest ISP, as determined parametrically.